# How to use Eclipse to create released signed apk?

Tags: android, apk, signing

I have been a Java programmer/instructor since Java was `Oak` (which is the development name for Java).

Where can one find how to use `eclipse` to sign an `app` for release?  I have found several how to `docs/web sites`, but not detailed enough for a newbie to this `android` world.

I have a screen that comes up that wants the `Alias`, organizational unit, etc... what are valid values for these entries?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Upon finding a tutorial (http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/02/sign-your-android-applications-for.html) which made this process more clear. It pointed out the alias name and the other fields too, and how they mattered, etc.

Comment: Here is the easiest and shortest method http://goo.gl/7ri2gh

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Right-click your project in Eclipse > Chose **Android Tool** > **Export Signed Application Package...**

This question has been answered before: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916053/application-signing). You'll find more to read on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: I agree an attempt to answer it has been done, but just as in your reply... vague answer.  As I wrote... when the screen comes up with the alias box, organizational unit box... etc.  What are valid values for these boxes?  Like an onHover Help pop up that says Alias: any value you want to use. This field has no effect on the keyStore, etc.  So newbies know what to put in the boxes.  If it is important data or not.  

That is what has not been answered, I could not find an answer to.

Comment: I'm truly sorry for my poor answer. My intention was never to imply something rough. I really have no good answer to that question, but to read the agreement one accepts downloading the SDK and the agreement one accepts when signing up for the Android Market. If nothing else is stated in those agreements, I think it is free of choice. Sincerely

Comment: Sorry for my frustration.  But where is the how to for this stuff?  Thanks for your reply.

Comment: This link will provide help in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file/22634313#22634313