# How to sign an android apk file

Tags: android, apk, signing

I am trying to sign my apk file. I can't figure out how to do it. I can't find good in-depth directions. I have very little programing experience, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this: [How to sign Android project apk](http://coderzheaven.com/2011/04/01/android-signing-apk/)

Comment: You can find a great tutorial about this here at http://www.androidcookers.co.cc/2012/06/signing-your-app-before-publishing-to.html

Comment: I used this complete tutorial from creating my own keystore to exporting a signed APK in Eclipse. http://www.mahadera.com/export-signed-android-apk-in-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The manual is clear enough. Please specify what part you get stuck with after you work through it, I'd suggest:

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Okay, a small overview without reference or eclipse around, so leave some space for errors, but it works like this

- Open your project in eclipse
- Press right-mouse - > tools (android tools?) - > export signed application (apk?)
- Go through the wizard:
- Make a new key-store. remember that password
- Sign your app
- Save it etc.

Also, from the link:

> Compile and sign with Eclipse ADT
>
> If you are using Eclipse with the ADT
>   plugin, you can use the Export Wizard
>   to export a signed .apk (and even
>   create a new keystore, if necessary).
>   The Export Wizard performs all the
>   interaction with the Keytool and
>   Jarsigner for you, which allows you to
>   sign the package using a GUI instead
>   of performing the manual procedures to
>   compile, sign, and align, as discussed
>   above. Once the wizard has compiled
>   and signed your package, it will also
>   perform package alignment with
>   zip align. Because the Export Wizard
>   uses both Keytool and Jarsigner, you
>   should ensure that they are accessible
>   on your computer, as described above
>   in the Basic Setup for Signing.
>
> To create a signed and aligned .apk in
>   Eclipse:
>
> 1. Select the project in the Package Explorer and select File >
>      Export.
> 2. Open the Android folder, select Export Android Application, and click
>      Next.
>
>    The Export Android Application wizard now starts, which will guide
>      you through the process of signing
>      your application, including steps for
>      selecting the private key with which
>      to sign the .apk (or creating a new
>      keystore and private key).
> 3. Complete the Export Wizard and your application will be compiled,
>      signed, aligned, and ready for
>      distribution.

Comment: I don't understand how to get started. I am using eclipse Version: Helios Service Release 1

Comment: i'v added something to my answer

Comment: but please read the WHOLE thing. there's some tips in the end for eclipse too

Comment: in the key creation what do i need to enter for the alias?

Comment: Did you read the manual? `-alias <alias_name> An alias for the key. Only the first 8 characters of the alias are used.` It's just an alias. A name, if you will. i'd suggest "firstkey" :-)

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand. How would I use this alias. What is its purpose?

Comment: What is the role of Keytool and Jarsigner?

Comment: Is there a way to disable the user input prompt for password??Instead if we can add it in main command only, jarsigner -verbose -keystore myCertificate.keystore D:Listv
iew.apk myKey??

Comment: the android notes are among the worst in the world - the one you references waxes lyrical about things that just aren't important. they really need to be condensed to a readable size

Answer (score 45):

Here is a guide on how to manually sign an APK. It includes info about the new `apk-signer` introduced in `build-tools 24.0.3` *(10/2016)*

## Automated Process:

Use this tool (uses the new apksigner from Google):

https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer

<sup>Disclaimer: Im the developer :)</sup>

## Manual Process:

### Step 1: Generate Keystore (only once)

You need to generate a keystore once and use it to sign your `unsigned` apk.
Use the [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) [provided by the JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830253/where-is-the-keytool-application) found in `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/`

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my.keystore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias app
```

### Step 2 or 4: Zipalign

[`zipalign`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html) [which is a tool provided by the Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442213/cannot-find-zip-align-when-publishing-app) found in e.g. `%ANDROID_HOME%/sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/` is a mandatory optimzation step if you want to upload the apk to the Play Store.

```
zipalign -p 4 my.apk my-aligned.apk
```

**Note:** when using the old `jarsigner` you need to zipalign *AFTER* signing. When using the new `apksigner` method you do it *BEFORE* signing (confusing, I know). [Invoking zipalign before apksigner works fine](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html) because apksigner preserves APK alignment and compression (unlike jarsigner).

You can *verify* the alignment with

```
zipalign -c 4 my-aligned.apk
```

### Step 3: Sign & Verify

#### Using build-tools 24.0.2 and older

Use [`jarsigner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) which, like the keytool, [comes with the JDK distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135699/where-is-jarsigner) found in  `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/` and use it like so:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my.keystore my-app.apk my_alias_name
```

and can be verified with

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose my_application.apk
```

#### Using build-tools 24.0.3 and newer

Android 7.0 introduces APK Signature Scheme v2, a new app-signing scheme that offers faster app install times and more protection against unauthorized alterations to APK files (See [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2) and [here](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2.html) for more details). Threfore Google implemented their [own apk signer called `apksigner`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) (duh!)
The script file can be found in `%ANDROID_HOME%/sdk/build-tools/24.0.3/` (the .jar is in the `/lib` subfolder). Use it like this

```
apksigner sign --ks my.keystore my-app.apk --ks-key-alias alias_name
```

and can be verified with

```
apksigner verify my-app.apk
```

[The official documentation can be found here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually)

Answer (score 11):

For users of IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio make these steps:
* From the menu `Build/Generate signed APK`
* You need to create a keystore path. From the dialog click `Create new`. You will create a jks file that includes your keys. Select folder, define a password. So your keystore ok.
* Create new key by for your application by using alias, key password, your name etc.
* Click next.
* From the dialog either select [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) or not.

Your signed APK file is ready.

Help file: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generate-signed-apk-wizard.html

Answer (score 10):

## APK Signing Process

To manually sign an Android APK file run these three commands:

1. **Generate Keystore file**

   ```
   keytool -genkey -v -keystore YOUR_KEYSTORE_NAME.keystore -alias ALIAS_NAME -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
   ```
2. **Sign Your APK file using `jarsigner`**

   ```
   jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore KEYSTORE_FILE_PATH UNSIGNED_APK_PATH ALIAS_NAME
   ```
3. **Align Signed APK using zipalign tool**

   ```
   zipalign -v 4 JARSIGNED_APK_FILE_PATH ZIPALIGNED_SIGNED_APK_FILE_PATH
   ```

## STEP 1

---

### `Generate Keystore file`

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore YOUR_KEYSTORE_NAME.keystore -alias ALIAS_NAME -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

### Example:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore id.keystore -alias MySignedApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

keystore password : **yourApp@123**
key password      : **yourApp@123**

### CMD O/P

```
D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp>keytool -genkey -v -keystore id.keystore
 -alias MySignedApp -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  MySignedApp Sample
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  Information Technology
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  MySignedApp Demo
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  Mumbai
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  Maharashtra
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  IN
Is CN=MySignedApp Demo, OU=Information Technology, O=MySignedApp Demo, L=Mumbai, ST=Maharashtra, C=IN corr
ect?
  [no]:  y

Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 10,
000 days
        for: CN=MySignedApp Demo, OU=Information Technology, O=MySignedApp Demo, L=Mumbai, ST=Maharashtra,
 C=IN
Enter key password for <MySignedApp>
        (RETURN if same as keystore password):
Re-enter new password:
[Storing id.keystore]

D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp>
```

---

## STEP 2

---

### `Sign your app with your private keystore using jarsigner`

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   KEYSTORE_FILE_PATH UNSIGNED_APK_PATH ALIAS_NAME

### Example

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\id.keystore D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedAppS1-release-unsigned.apk id
```

### CMD O/P

```
D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp>jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -
digestalg SHA1 -keystore D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\id.keystore D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedAppS1-release-unsigned.apk id ---
ect
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
   adding: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   adding: META-INF/---.SF
   adding: META-INF/---.RSA
  signing: AndroidManifest.xml
  ..... 
    signing: classes.dex
  signing: lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar
  signing: lib/armeabi/libkonyjsvm.so
jar signed.

Warning:
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not
be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-02-07) or after an
y future revocation date.

D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp>
```

---

### **`Verify that your APK is signed`**

> jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs JARSIGNED_APK_FILE_PATH

### Example

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs MySignedAppS1-release-unsigned.apk
```

### CMD O/P

```
D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp>jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs MySignedAppS1-release-unsigned.apk
 s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not b
e able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2044-02-09) or after any
 future revocation date.

D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp>
```

## STEP 3

---

### Align the final APK package using zipalign

> zipalign -v 4 JARSIGNED_APK_FILE_PATH ZIPALIGNED_SIGNED_APK_FILE_PATH_WITH_NAME_ofSignedAPK

### Example

```
zipalign -v 4 D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedAppS1-release-unsigned.apk D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedApp.apk
```

### CMD O/P

```
D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0>zipalign -v 4 D:\ru\ru_doc\Signed_apk\MySignedApp\28.09.16
_prod_playstore\MySignedAppS1-release-unsigned.apk D:\ru\ru_doc\Signed_apk\MySignedApp\28.09.16_prod
_playstore\MySignedApp.apk
Verifying alignment of D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedApp.apk (
4)...

  4528613 classes.dex (OK - compressed)
 5656594 lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar (OK - compressed)
 5841869 lib/armeabi/libkonyjsvm.so (OK - compressed)
Verification succesful

D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0>
```

---

### **`Verify that your APK is Aligned successfully`**

> zipalign -c -v 4 YOUR_APK_PATH

### Example

```
zipalign -c -v 4 D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedApp.apk
```

### CMD O/P

```
D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0>zipalign -c -v 4 D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedApp.apk
Verifying alignment of D:\ru\SignedBuilds\MySignedApp\MySignedApp.apk (
4)...

 4453984 res/drawable/zoomout.png (OK)
 4454772 res/layout/tabview.xml (OK - compressed)
 4455243 res/layout/wheel_item.xml (OK - compressed)
 4455608 resources.arsc (OK)
 4470161 classes.dex (OK - compressed)
 5597923 lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar (OK - compressed)
 5783198 lib/armeabi/libkonyjsvm.so (OK - compressed)
Verification succesful

D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0>
```

### Note:

The verify command is just to check whether APK is built and signed correctly!

#### References

- [signing-manually](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually)
- [androidapk-code-signing-process](https://learnkony.wordpress.com/2015/06/12/androidapk-code-signing-process/#Generation)

I hope this will help one and all :)

Answer (score 8):

Don't worry...! Follow these below steps and you will get your signed .apk file. I was also worry about that, but these step get ride me off from the frustration.
Steps to sign your application:

1. Export the unsigned package:

Right click on the project in Eclipse -> Android Tools -> Export Unsigned Application Package *(like here we export our GoogleDriveApp.apk to Desktop)*

**Sign the application using your keystore and the jarsigner tool (follow below steps):**

Open cmd-->change directory where your "jarsigner.exe" exist (like here in my system it exist at "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin"

Now enter belwo command in cmd:

> jarsigner -verbose -keystore c:\users\android\debug.keystore
>   c:\users\pir fahim\Desktops\GoogleDriveApp.apk my_keystore_alias

It will ask you to provide your password:
Enter Passphrase for keystore:
It will sign your apk.**To verify that the signing is successful you can run:**

> jarsigner -verify c:\users\pir fahim\Desktops\GoogleDriveApp.apk

It should come back with:
jar verified.

**Method 2**

If you are using eclipse with ADT, then it is simple to compiled, signed, aligned, and ready the file for distribution.what you have to do just follow this steps.

- File > Export.
- Export android application
- Browse-->select your project
- Next-->Next

These steps will compiled, signed and zip aligned your project and now you are ready to distribute your project or upload at Google Play store.

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed, was using a new online build tool and had to use my previous keystore, not their newly generated one. Only thing i was missing was ZIP ALIGNing the apk, so if anybody has the same problem, go here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22682132/826194

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and was solved by checking the min sdk version in the manifest.
It was set to 15 (ICS), but my phone was running 10(Gingerbread)