# How to Sign Android APK

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sign an android apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

I am developing one application which is based on GPS. It displays the map correctly on my device, but when I install it on another device the map is not displayed.

How do I sign my app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You should refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).

For map key process refer this [doc](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint).

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate `MapView` keys: one for debug and one for release. [See the Google API document on this topic.](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html)