# Signing APK from developer

Tags: android, apk, keystore, sign

**Things to know:**

1. I'm kinda new to programming
2. I have installed Eclipse with the Android platform loaded on my Macbook Pro
3. I have 2 PCs as well for further troubleshooting and flexibility

I commissioned a developer to port an iOS app to the Android platform.  I did not build the app myself, I paid to have other people do it.  I was able to run the avd and emulator and install/uninstall/reinstall with success through the adb protocol.  Now I'm on to sign the APK for release in the Android Marketplace, except that's where I'm stuck.  I have attempted and researched the hell out of this to no avail.  I *think* the issue I'm running into is the materials I find are outdated.

**Methods I've tried:**

1. Using command prompt on my PC, I used the keytool command via the instructions [here](http://www.talkandroid.com/android-forums/android-market-reviews/1317-tutorial-signing-your-apk-publishing.html) and was able to get through the first half, but when prompted for the second half I kept getting "cannot find jvm.dll".  [This guy](http://photics.com/signing-my-google-android-application-keytoolexe-jarsignerexe) had a similar issue, but no instructions on how to solve it, which he did apparently.  NOTE: I did not find jarsigner.exe in ANYWHERE on any of my computers.  I downloaded it from a website. Could be corrupt or invalid I suppose.  Could never get a signed APK.
2. I found "signapk.rar" from [this site](http://photics.com/signing-my-google-android-application-keytoolexe-jarsignerexe) and it actually seemed to work.  I followed the instructions to a T and it produced the signed APK like it was supposed to.  The problem was when I attempted to upload it, the Marketplace told me it expired before the 2033 date, whatever that was.  So I assume that the code in this program had a validity entry that was large enough.  I don't know how to change that, if that is the issue.
3. I came across Portecle just yesterday and was able to create a keystore and a certificate.  I know where they are in my directory, but I don't know how to use that to sign the APK.  It's terribly confusing.
4. Signing in Eclipse. This is the least successful method because I can't for the life of me figure out how to work the damn thing.  I know I can't just 'import apk' and it work like magic, but that'd be great if it did.  I created a new project and imported the file system after changing my APK to a ZIP. One time it imported the manifest and the other time it didn't do anything.  I'm certain it's user error.

I understand if this were an easy process, everybody could be a developer.  That's obviously not the case, so I'm trying to figure it out on my own while my developer is out of the country.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: In my case using OSX has worked pretty much flawlessly when it comes to tools needed for Android development. Maybe you could try using your Macbook and follow official [signing documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sign an android apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

1. Assuming you have the keystore (private key to sign the apk) already generated by you.You can use the command line to do the signing without eclipse or android studio if the yourApp-unsigned.apk is already generated by your vendor or you
2. You are Using Windows for the below steps

Signing the apk:
Add the path for your jdk bin to your system variables (if you don't know how to do, that look for it its easy search for how to add path to windows system variables)
This is my jdk path (use yours)

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin

open Command Line and type the below using your App apk and keystore key

> jarsigner -verbose -keystore c:\users\android\myAppKeyStore.keystore
>   c:\users\blabla\Desktops\myAppAPK.apk my_keystore_alias

if success, it will promote you to enter key phrase/password of your private key (the one used for your private key generation which you should know)

Verify it was signed Successfully using the command line

> jarsigner -verify c:\users\blabla\Desktops\myAppSignedAPK.apk