# Intall new apk and delete previous

Tags: android, mobile, installation, apk

Good day everyone.

Here`s the situation. I got an android application and it`s tring to update it`s self. So it downloads the new version of apk file and does.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package_archive");
        intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mApp.startActivity(intent);
```

Installation starts but stops with message "Application can`t be installed". I figured out that the reason is - my new apk is not signed, and previous version was.

So i need my application to remove it`s self and install new (unsinged) apk. Or do anything to get my new apk insalled and run. And i need to do it in previous application code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application must be signed (developer-signed straight from Eclipse, for example, or with your own generated key) before it can be installed. Period. So, you need to sign it first, AND it has to be with the same key--otherwise you'll get an installation error.

See: [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

I can't think of any reason that the app would have to be uninstalled prior to installing a new version, except for app compatibility reasons (like your new app handles saved data differently or something).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to the following links :

[How to sign an android apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

or

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html