# I get error in eclipse when i try to export the project to apk

Tags: android, eclipse

I get error in eclipse when i try to export the project to apk so I could not solve it

the message  that appear is

```
keytool error:  java.lang.Exception: Key pair not generated, alias
<.......> already exists
```

so can any one to help

Answer (score 0):

Did you generate the key and use it? Its straight forward. You must have a key to sign the application. You can generate the apk only after that.

Comment: I generate the key it was work and I export many program to apk until something happen in these problem appeare

Comment: Probably the same alias name for the key already exists, while you are trying to create a new alias for the same name.

Answer (score 0):

How are your signing the Application? Heres a good step by step to digitally signing you application. [How to sign an android apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

Answer (score 0):

For this simply regenerate you certificate again follow these steps.

```
   1)keytool -genkey -v -keystore mycertificate.keystore -alias mykey -keyalg 
   RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 1000
   2)  jarsigner -verbose -keystore mycertificate.keystore D:\app.apk mykey
   3) jarsigner -verify app.apk
     If it  will have done then shows a message "successfully verified"
   4) zipalign -v 4 D:\app.apk D:\signedapp.apk

  it will generate new certificate. enjoy
```