# How to set up gradle and android studio to do release build?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, release, android-gradle-plugin

I want to build android app and start signing it. 
For that I need to have Release version of apk. Google documentation suggests only Eclipse and ant ways to have release builds: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile

However I cannot find how to force gradle build release version of apk. `build.gradle` does not give any hints either. `gradlew tasks` suggests, that there is no install Release configuration, but uninstall release exists:

```
Install tasks
-------------
installDebug - Installs the Debug build
installTest - Installs the Test build for the Debug build
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build
uninstallRelease - Uninstalls the Release build
uninstallTest - Uninstalls the Test build for the Debug build
```

My `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile project(":libraries:ActionBarSherlock")
    compile project(":libraries:CollabsibleSearchMenu")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

What I am missing?

Comment: I don't currently use Gradle in Android Studio, but the way to do it using the original Ant build is to simply use `Build` -> `Generate Signed APK` from the menu.

Comment: Thanks I missed that, it will do.
But still I want to know how to generate release version of unsigned package seperately and then do signing and whatever I want with it.

Comment: you should get automatically a release and debug version of your  under your build variants. If you want an unsigned package let me know.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

in the latest version of android studio, you can just do:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

or `aR` for short.  This will produce an unsigned release apk.  Building a signed apk can be done similarly or you can use Build -> Generate Signed Apk in Android Studio.

[See the docs here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks)

Here is my build.gradle for reference:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')

}

buildTypes {
    release {

    }
}
```

Comment: In the latest version of Android Studio (0.2.11) Generate Signed Apk no longer works. You're directed to set up a signing configuration in your gradle.bundle file, which (presumably) has to be run by hand from the command line unless you're willing to hardcode your password there: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Signing-Configurations

Comment: Why the newer the Android Studio, the more difficult to use?

Answer (score 151):

1. open the `Build Variants` pane, typically found [along the lower left side of the window](http://prntscr.com/6u7j3s):

[image: Build Variants]

2. set `debug` to `release`
3. `shift+f10` run!!

then, Android Studio will execute `assembleRelease` task and install xx-release.apk to your device.

Comment: how do you open Build Variants?  is this something i can do in Android Studio?

Comment: The build variants is on the left hand side, please see the attached screenshot for a better idea of location :)
[Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/6u7j3s)

Comment: Tried this. But getting error : "app-release-unsigned.apk is not signed. Please configure the signing information for the selected flavor using the Project Structure dialog.Open Project Structure Dialog"

Comment: @jrhamza Follow it prompts you to add a release key.

Comment: Amazing how well hidden this simple switch is if you've never had the Build Variants window open!

Comment: It would've been too obvious to put it in the configurations!

Answer (score 34):

No need to update gradle for making release application in Android studio.If you were eclipse user then it will be so easy for you. If you are new then follow the steps

1: Go to the "Build" at the toolbar section.
2: Choose "Generate Signed APK..." option.
[image]

3:fill opened form and go next
4 :if you already have .keystore or .jks then choose that file enter your password and alias name and respective password.
5: Or don't have .keystore or .jks file then click on Create new... button as shown on pic 1 then fill the form.[image]

Above process was to make build manually. If You want android studio to automatically Signing Your App

In Android Studio, you can configure your project to sign your release APK automatically during the build process:

On the project browser, right click on your app and select Open Module Settings.
On the Project Structure window, select your app's module under Modules.
Click on the Signing tab.
Select your keystore file, enter a name for this signing configuration (as you may create more than one), and enter the required information.
[image]
Figure 4. Create a signing configuration in Android Studio.

Click on the Build Types tab.
Select the release build.
Under Signing Config, select the signing configuration you just created.
[image]
Figure 5. Select a signing configuration in Android Studio.

4:Most Important thing that make debuggable=false at gradle.

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
           minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-  android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        debuggable false
        jniDebuggable false
        renderscriptDebuggable false
        zipAlignEnabled true
       }
     }
```

visit for more in info [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: You are a life saver brother.

Answer (score 22):

To activate the `installRelease` task, you simply need a `signingConfig`. That is all.

From http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks:

> Finally, the plugin creates install/uninstall tasks for all build
>   types (debug, release, test), as long as they can be installed (which
>   requires signing).

#### Here is what you want:

```
Install tasks
-------------
installDebug - Installs the Debug build
installDebugTest - Installs the Test build for the Debug build
installRelease - Installs the Release build
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build
uninstallDebugTest - Uninstalls the Test build for the Debug build
uninstallRelease - Uninstalls the Release build   <--- release
```

#### Here is how to obtain the `installRelease` task:

Example `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'demo'
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName '1.0'
  }

  signingConfigs {
      release {
          storeFile <file>
          storePassword <password>
          keyAlias <alias>
          keyPassword <password>
      }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that we keep the password in a readable format? How to handle for projects in public repository, in order to keep the passwords private?

Comment: You can put in a local `gradle.properties` or store them in the CI.

Comment: Could not find method storeFile()

Comment: Set `storeFile file(filename)`

Comment: signingConfig signingConfigs.release in build types made the difference for me!

Answer (score 22):

This is a procedure to configure run release version

1- Change build variants to release version.

[image]

2- Open project structure.
[image]

3- Change default config to $signingConfigs.release
[image]

Comment: You are a god among men

Comment: Amennnnnnnnnnn.

Answer (score 8):

To compile with release build as shown below:

[image]