# How to run android app in release not in debug?

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-api-3, android-build-type

In my app I'm using google maps. Now, I realized that you have a build google maps key and release google maps key. When I launch my signed apk into the app store for testing the google maps screen goes grey. And i have to keep signing a new apk and loading it into play store and then test it.

How do I test a release build? Please provide very simple and easy step by step instructions or if you know how to solve the problem with google maps that would be helpful.

Here is a screen shot of how i set up my google maps api in the console for my release one.

[image]

Comment: `Have to keep signing a new apk and loading it into play store and then test it` you can define which your gradle > http://stackoverflow.com/a/18776949/5188159

Comment: do you need the answer for your gray screen as well ;)

Comment: @Charuක hi there, so i just solved it actually (im having some luck here in the last 20mins). But, what i did was make a new key, and i made it completely open. Then, i went to project view. app->src->release->res->values-> google_maps_api and i entered that new key that had no restrictions. and it ended up working (in the release build). Did you have another (or better) way?

Comment: yes that was i mentioning if you forgot to add that key in your release google map it goes gray at release mode

Comment: @Charuක oh im sorry, it was hidden for some reason. But thank you, for the solution!

Comment: Okay good luck :D

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Test a release build**

[image]

1. open `Build Variants`

[image]

2. set `debug` to `release`
3. Build and Run

**For gray screen** 
Once you have got the release SHA set in dev console

- This is main reason that I forget most of the time

> You have **two** *google_maps_api.xml* files
>
> One in this folder:
>
> *app/src/**debug**/res/values*
>
> Other in this folder:
>
> *app/src/**release**/res/values*
>
> But only the debug one contains your API key probably.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gradle` tasks to run a release build on emulator.

Default task name is `installRelease`

just start emulator and fire below command from terminal

```
./gradlew installRelease
```

this will install release build into emulator.

Comment: how would i do this if i wanted to test on my phone?

Comment: it will install to all connected devices/emulators

Comment: i see, i actually just recently found a nice and fast way to do it which i will post below.

Comment: For me it says "task installRelease not found in root project XXX