# Can't generate signed APK react native app

Tags: react-native, release, signed-apk

I'm trying to generate signed apk version of my react native app from android studio

always the same error appears at the end

Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'

I've been looking for a solution for two days
Is there anyone who can save my life

Comment: If you scroll up a bit through the compiler output, you should be able to find a more detailed stacktrace

Comment: Maybe this link can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619753/how-to-build-a-release-apk-in-android-studio

Answer (score 0):

When I get errors like this they are mostly solved by doing a Build -> Clean Project and then trying again.