# How can I convert my Flutter app to IOS and APK?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I made a private messenger app only for my friends and family. But I don't know how can I convert my source code to an app. I don't want to release my app into the play store or app store. I just want to make it for my friends.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a 'release' APK in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619753/how-to-build-a-release-apk-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 4):

Use `flutter build apk --release` for building an Android app.

For iOS, use `flutter build ios --release` and then go to XCode and Archive the app.

Answer (score 0):

On your terminal, run the command below for android

```
flutter build apk
```

And then the one below for iOS

```
flutter build ipa
```