# I'm having a problem with Admob ads not showing up on Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ads

((I'm having a problem with Admob ads not showing up on Android))

Hi
I have added all the admob code correctly
But when I run my test ad, it says:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juUOX.png)

And when I connect it to admob, it doesn't show any ads

**activity_main.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private AdView mAdView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });


    mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

       }
   }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.Stories">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@drawable/welcom_image"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/welcom_image"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
    >
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.Stories.welcom"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.Stories.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" />


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

**build.gradle(app) :**

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.example.Stories'
    minSdk 29
    targetSdk 33
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard- 
 rules.pro'
    }
 }
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
 }

 dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Please help in solving this problem

Comment: Have you tried release mode yet?

Comment: Release mode what ?

Comment: Do you know how to make an APK for Live that we can upload to Google Play? if not then follow this url :-> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28938286/9305266

Comment: Same problem, test ads work but real ads don't show in the app when I upload to play store.