# Can't generate release signed apk at Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I can actually not Generate Signed Apk files in Android Studio.

When I click the point in the menu Gradle is running and running. The longest time was 30min after that I killed the process. The unsigned apk works very good.

If have tried it with `gradlew assembleRelease --debug` and it freeze by this point:

```
writing android/support/; size 0...
writing android/support/v7/; size 0...
writing android/support/v7/recyclerview/; size 0...
writing android/support/v7/util/; size 0...
writing android/support/v7/widget/; size 0...
writing android/support/v7/widget/helper/; size 0...
writing android/support/v7/widget/util/; size 0...
writing classes.dex; size 291624...﻿
```

Does anyone had the same problem or how I can fix it?

Please help :-(

Here my Gradle File:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
defaultConfig {
applicationId "mypackage"
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
versionCode 23
versionName "1.5.1"

}
buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.7.8.1'
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:4.0.0@aar') {
transitive = true
}
compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:1.2.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:3.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
}
```

Comment: visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17637759/5202007) or [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19620857/5202007).

Comment: @Tauqir yes I know but since 1 week it doesn't work. By other projects that I have it work everything :( I don't know where the issue is.

Comment: are you facing multidex issue as there are multiple libraries ?

Comment: I get no issues he is building and building

Comment: try to add these two lines below : proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
1.debuggable false 2.jniDebuggable false

Comment: also in manifest add android:debuggable="false" in application tag.

Comment: @Tauqir nope the same as before the freezed at this point 

writing .readme; size 109...
writing META-INF/; size 0...
writing android/; size 0...
writing android/support/; size 0...
writing android/support/design/; size 0...
writing android/support/design/internal/; size 0...
writing android/support/design/widget/; size 0...
writing classes.dex; size 203468...

> Building 89% > :app:preDexRelease

Comment: Please once try [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: or [dex errors](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28606782/5202007)

Comment: @Tauqir thank you very much the dex errors answer has worked :D