# Error sending APK PhoneGap to Google Play

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, phonegap-build

By submitting APK PhoneGap to Google Play features the following error:

> SEND NEW APK FOR PRODUCTION
>
> Sending failed you uploaded an APK debuggable. For security reasons,
>   disable debugging before publishing it on Google Play. Learn more
>   about APKs debuggable .. You have sent an APK signed in debug mode.
>   Sign your APK in Release mode. Learn more about how to sign. Use a
>   different package name. "io.cordova.hellocordova" already exists in
>   Google Play.

How to solve it?

Comment: Sign your apk with release key. See http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a release build for Android, we can use the following cordova cli command,

```
$ cordova build --release android
```

we can find our unsigned APK file in **platforms/android/build/outputs/apk**.Now, we need to sign the unsigned APK and run an alignment utility on it to optimize it and prepare it for the app store.Let’s generate our private key using the **keytool** command that comes with the JDK.

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

You’ll first be prompted to create a password for the keystore. Then, answer the rest of the nice tools’s questions and when it’s all done, you should have a file called my-release-key.keystore created in the current directory.

To sign the unsigned APK, run the **jarsigner** tool which is also included in the JDK with the following command,

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name
```

This signs the apk in place. Finally, we need to run the zip align tool to optimize the APK. The **zipalign** tool can be found in **/path/to/Android/sdk/build-tools/VERSION/zipalign**.use this command to zipalign the apk,

```
$ zipalign -v 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
```

Now we have our final release binary called HelloWorld.apk and we can release this on the Google Play Store for all the world to enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You are probally sending the Debug mode Apk located at "bin" folder. It's incompatible with Google Play deploy.

You should create a release version, like Rohit5k2 suggested. To do that, just do the following:

[Create release APK Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17637700/release-version-of-apk-in-android-studio)

[Create release APK on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417122/how-to-use-eclipse-to-create-released-signed-apk)

Hope it helps! Best regards! O/