# How to sign a certificate for my App for Android Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, phonegap-build

I get this error when Im trying to upload my App to Google Play:

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode. Learn more about signing.
You have exceeded the daily APK upload limit. Please upload your APK tomorrow.

Im using PhoneGap Builder and I uploaded a file index.html and I get the file converted to a .APK file, but I can not upload the App to Google Play, It asking about the license key.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are trying to upload the apk which is Signed by debug certificate. You need to create your own certificate and then sign your application with that.

[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) is the best tutorials for that. And [How to sign an android apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file) is also a very good resource.

---

Image representation is at [Build Android application package file (APK) using Eclipse IDE and Android Developer Tools (ADT) Plugin](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/23/build-android-application-package-file-apk-using-eclipse-ide-and-android-development-tools-adt-plugin)

---

As you are using PhoneGap so [Android Signing from PhoneGap](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-signing-android) is the official documentation.

Comment: I get this error in my terminal -bash: zipalign: command not found, when Im using your link "How to sign an android apk file" and this when I use this code: zipalign -v 4 D:Listview.apk D:SignedListview.apk. What could be wrong?

Comment: hey easy way to do that from export wizard... (the way which you are trying, you need to install zipalign). See the last link, there you will find some images and screen shots to be clear. Don't do step 1 from there, other are fine.

Comment: Thanks, but what is export wizard? And how to install zipalign? I have read your links, but It dont work...

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: Ok then try using your previous attempt. You can be found zipalign under the ‘tools’ folder of the Android SDK. Here is a tutorilas about zipalign http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/what-is-zipalign-in-android-and-how-it-works-complete-guide/

Comment: Added official doc of PhoneGap for the same

Comment: Thanks, but i can not find zipalign under the ‘tools’ folder of the Android SDK. Where can I find the tools folder? Im using https://build.phonegap.com to conert my index.html file to a apk file.

Comment: path is under your android sdk `/sdk/tools/zipalign`. That must be there.  If you doesn't find, you need to download again.