# How we make Signed APK for google play store?

Tags: android, google-play, android-install-apk

I have completed my android app and now wanted to publish it on android market. I have an account on google play store for android apps. But when tried to upload my apk file it gives error.

> [image: this is error details]

I have read many tutorials but fail to upload.

[How to sign an android apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

Comment: it seems like your apk is not `zipalign`. Execute this command `D:\android-sdk\android-sdk\tools>zipalign -f -v 4 inputapkname.apk outputapkname.apk`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file

Answer (score 2):

First Right Click On project And Click On export
[image]

And Then Follow Instruction

[image]

Comment: i have completed these steps but when i am trying to upload this shows the following error.

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid. Learn more about signing.
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.

Comment: Then you have to change package name of application

Comment: i have done this but failed to upload and
Upoad fail
 You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid. Learn more about signing.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at to this developer link,

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

- open your project in eclips
- press right-mouse, tools (android tools?) - > export signed application (apk?)
- go trough the wizzard:
- make a new key-store. remember that password
- sign your app
- save it etc.

Comment: i have completed these steps but when i am trying to upload this shows the following error.

Upload failed
You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that is not yet valid. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that is currently valid. Learn more about signing.
You need to use a different package name because "com.example" is restricted.

Comment: Then I guess you need to create a new signin key for your self.

Comment: simple alias , passwd, org name etc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46409/discussion-between-deemi47-and-user3243163)

Answer (score 1):

[image]If you are trying to export your signed apk then you should go with.

```
Project -> Export -> Export Signed Apk -> Go to Wizard -> Create New Keystore -> Create Password(Remember it) -> Fill Info and Give alias name for your app -> Sign your app ->Finally Save it or finish it.
```

You have to use ***Zip align tool*** which is allocated in ***tools*** folder of SDK.

You should use this way in your command prompt at where your zip align tool path is required.

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

Where  infile.apk is your source file which is signed apk and ***outfile.apk*** is your destination file which is output file.. And you must use that signed output apk file and upload it on Google play.

Comment: in file is your apk name to which you have to zip it and using this zip create new destination apk whatever you have given name here in my post it is outfile.apk and this is your final apk and it will be uploaded on google play

Comment: Actually i am asking about the path of infile.apk? when i export a signed apk i save it in a new folder.

Comment: no...you have to put it in tools folder...see my screenshot so you will understand