# You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned error

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have just finished and signed the apk through android studio, 
then I have did an apk protect through apkprotect.com 
when I am trying to upload the apk to play store I got this error " You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again. " 
if I upload the original apk I got no errors,

I have tried to add zipalign true in the build.gradle but nothing happened
I have tried also disable and enable proguard .

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can run zipalign manually in command line:

```
zipalign [-f] [-v] <alignment> infile.apk outfile.apk
```

Note that zipalign is located inside ${sdk.dir}\tools

For more details visit [zipalign](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html)

---

[Update]

Also, If you need to sign it you can run:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore YOURKEYSTORE unsigned.apk alias_name
```

(**jarsigner** is located inside java JDK_HOME/bin)

Comment: I have just tried that with a protected apk, got this error from play store " You uploaded an unsigned APK. You need to create a signed APK "

Comment: If apk is not signed, you should sign it before zipalign. For more details http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

Comment: I have did that through Android Studio => generate signed apk

Comment: yes, but after you used apkprotect.com, apk became unsigned again. I never used apkprotect, but I think you didn't provided your keystore right?  It can't sign you apk without keystore

Comment: Just tried to use apkprotect, it removed certificate from META-INF, so I signed and zipaligned apk and it worked!

Comment: jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore YOURKEYSTORE unsigned.apk alias_name

Comment: jarsigner is located inside  java JDK_HOME/bin

Comment: Interesting, I can't disable zip align in my case. Event if I'm using `gradlew assembleRelease` directly.

Comment: what is infile.apk and outfile.apk in this case? Thanks

Comment: @Gediminas infile.apk is the original apk which should be zipaligned and outfile.apk is the final zipaligned apk.

Answer (score 20):

I got the same "You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned... blah, blah" error when by mistake I tried to upload a DEBUG version of my .apk file to Google Play. It's a bit misleading error because the real problem is that you cannot distribute a debug version which additionally is not signed with your Google Android Developer key. (You can only upload an .apk compiled as release version, and it must be signed, which happens in the same step, at least if you're using Eclipse).

Make sure you distribute an .apk file which is your Signed Release version, as described here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile

Answer (score 7):

This question and its answers are old; so we expect things to change. As of today, the zipalign tool is in the ANDROID_HOME directory under build-tools/[version]/ so my path is currently:

```
/android-sdk/build-tools/22.0.0/zipalign
```

Using the zipalign tool is not necessarily the answer here though, what you actually need to do is sign your apk.

Comment: I was using the wrong apk.... I used one in "<project directory>\\build\outputs\apk" instead the one in the base of the project directory

Comment: this was my case too, i was trying to upload an archive generated by xamarin. then after reading this i created an adhoc publish and signed it

Answer (score 7):

Steps if using Xamarin for VS2017:

1. Build project
2. Right click and `Archive` project
3. Use `Ad Hoc` distribution channel
4. Sign your APK with your Signing Identity and `Save As` to produce an APK that is ZIP aligned.

Your APK can be uploaded to Google Play.

Comment: VS2019 update; Additionally, you have to uncheck [Fast Deployment] and build for [Release] when you try to do this. The Ad-hoc channel will also allow you to create a new signing keystore so you don't have to mess around with that if you don't have the appetite.

Answer (score 6):

I was using Cordova, uploaded a signed APK but still got this error.

The ziptool is what helped me, it's located at `~AndroidSDK\build-tools\24.0.0\zipalign.exe`

So for example :

```
"~\AndroidSDK\build-tools\24.0.0\zipalign.exe" -f -v 4 android-release-signed.apk android-release-signed-zipaligned.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using Cordova and the command line getting this error.  I opened the project in Android Studio and used Android Studio to build the signed apk and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

When using the Cordova node.js CLI without going through Android Studio, it is necessary to update the `PATH` environmental variable to include the android build tools:

```
%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\29.0.2
```

Obviously the version number will change over time. Remember to close any CLI windows and re-open them to recognize the newly added path.