# Android Studio zipalignment doens't work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app for android in the Play Store, and I want to upload a new version, so I generated a release apk, but when I try to upload it to the play store (I'm dutch, so I don't now exactly what it is in English) That there is no zipalign, I searched, but I didn't found useful answers, so does anyone knows how to fix this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681907/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-is-not-zip-aligned-error

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! when I downloaded the new Android Studio Preview 4 it worked again!