# Got error in application after update from google play store

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

Updating my 2nd version on google play store for beta testing I got error:

> "You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned. You will need to run a
>   zip align tool on your APK and upload it again".

I get this error on My first version that was developed in eclipse whereas the new version is in android studio.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681907/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-is-not-zip-aligned-error

Comment: There seems to be an issue with Android Studio 2.2 Preview 3, You have to download Preview 2 or use the stable version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Furthermore zipalign must only be performed after the .apk file has been signed with your private key. If you perform zipalign before signing, then the signing procedure will undo the alignment. Also, do not make alterations to the aligned package. Alterations to the archive, such as renaming or deleting entries, will potentially disrupt the alignment of the modified entry and all later entries. And any files added to an "aligned" archive will not be aligned.

[You can read here more about zipalign](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign.html)

Answer (score 0):

This error due to you are uploading apk which is not zip aligned. So first created signed apk through zip aligned from the keystore which you used previously to create signed apk for already live application.