# Can't distribute apk to Google Store with desired architectures

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, developer-console

I've made a Xamarin Android app in Visual Studio 2015 Community with Xamarin.
Until recently, I could publish it with no problems for beta testing and I had ~10.000 supported devices.
After I've updated Xamarin to 4.3.0.784, the publish option was replaced by Build>Archive. When I use this new option and distribute my app to Google Store, I have just 1632 supported devices.

I've noticed that on the APK Details page in Google Developer Console, it lists just arm64-v8a as "Native Platforms". In my previous builds that worked, I had all 5 platforms. No matter what supported architectures I select in Visual Studio project properties > Android Options> Advanced, after I distribute APK Details in Developer Console shows arm64-v8a.

Am I missing something or there's a bug in the new tools? What I want to achieve is to have an application in store with the supported architectures that I've selected in VS, so I won't be limited to the 1632 devices.

Comment: have you tried doing it directly on play store page? if you get same error

Comment: Do you mean uploading the APK manually? I've tried but it says that the APK is not zipaligned. I've tryied to do it manualy from cmd, but if I use the output APK, it still says that the APK is not zipaligned. I may be using the zipalign utility incorrectly, but I would prefer to distribute trough VS over manual.

Comment: strange. i had often problem uploading with VS2015 whenever I change supported OS or cpu architecture but it usually works doing it manually. Have you maybe changed something on android options like "Enable Multi-Dex" or "Enable Proguard". zipaligned thing is related to those as i can remember

Comment: see this topic also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681907/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-is-not-zip-aligned-error

Comment: I haven't changed them recently, I'm sure they are in the same state as when I had no problems. I have Multi-Dex checked and ProGuard unchecked. I'll check the link, thank you

Comment: Couple things to check. 1) Is this a fat binary? Does it include all of the architectures? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/cpu_architectures/#How_to_Specify_Supported_Architectures It sounds like you are only making an APK for one architecture. 2) Did you change your API difference between MinimumSDK -> TargetSDK? Having a decent gap between will also increase your device compatibility range.

Comment: 1) I have one apk that includes all architectures (if that means that generate one apk per abi is unchecked). I've also tried checking and unchecking different combinations. After I distribute it invariably lists just arm64-v8 in APK Details    2) I have Minimum SDK at lvl 16 (4.1) and Target Frakework at 4.4. The supported devices include new devices but not old ones (ex: Galaxy S6 and S7 are included, all older models are not), so I think the problem is strictly the fact that the apk is targeted to arm64-v8a.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I distributed it ad hoc to my drive, zipaligned it manually and uploaded it. It gave a bunch of errors about devices being served by more than 1 version of the APK when trying to publish. Apparently, the VS publishing process messed with the version codes also (I had 1,2,3,4,5 , now they are something like 232329, 232932 etc.) Some are for all platforms, some just for 64bit and I can't explain how that happened.

I still can't publish because of this error and I ran out of patience to surf the net all day so I can use the Build->Archive feature. So I created a new application and uploaded the apk by hand. (this app is in beta so it's ok to make another one). Everything is fine with the new one, 12.000 devices supported for the same APK that had 1600 devices supported.

Still don't understand what happened but it looks bad.
I consider this topic closed.