# Updating Android Application in Play Store Signing issue

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'll try my best to convey what my problem is, but I am having issues updating a clients application that is currently in the Play Store. The old version of the app was created by different developers.

- The previous version of the app by the looks of things was created using Adobde Air, I don't have any experience at all with Adobe Air, so not too sure about the signing process with the APKs.
- My new version is a new project (with same package name) created in Android Studio.
- I obviously need to sign the release APK with the same certificate as the previous version. Can I do this via Android Studio using the Build > Generate Signed APK?
- Will the previous developers have to provide a .keystore or .jks file? as I said i'm not sure how the signing process works when using Adobe Air.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: To sign Android APKs built with AIR I use self-signed certificate files in PKCS12 (I believe) format. I'm not sure about technical details because it's somehow under the hood of publishing process for AS3/Flash developers. I just provide *.p12 file I have with the password I used to create it in the relevant interfaces (if I publish with Adobe Flash) or scripts (if I publish with FlashDevelop/Flex SDK/AIR SDK).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can build an apk and have the original keystore file you can sign it via the command line.

Take a look here:

[You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681907/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-is-not-zip-aligned-error)

You'll need to do the jarsigner step first, then the zipalign on the resulting file. 4 works for me as the alignment value.