# APK is not zip aligned while pushing APK from jenkins to Play store

Tags: android, jenkins, google-play, apk, jenkins-cli

I am able to sign apk and upload to play store manually But when I try to push APK to play store from **jenkins** , I am getting following error.

**APK is not zip aligned.**

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You can find answer here [APK is not zip aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681907/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-is-not-zip-aligned-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You uploaded an APK that is not zip aligned error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681907/you-uploaded-an-apk-that-is-not-zip-aligned-error)

Comment: @Said  where to add in jenkins. It  woks fine when I normally build I am having problem only with Jenkins.

Comment: @APP where to add in jenkins. It woks fine when I normally build I am having problem only with Jenkins