# Why i can't sign my android application into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play, signing

What i have is an android application and i'm trying to upload it to play store and i have created account is everything is correct and i have created a store key for my app , but when i try to upload it i get the following message :
[image]

So i searched and i found out that i didn't signed my app before uploading it and i have searched how to signed it inside eclipse and i found the following steps : 
[image]

But in the project explorer i couldn't find **open module setting** so i can sign my key store like this :
[image]

Why this is happening? can you help me to upload it please? i'm new at android :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file

Answer (score 0):

you can choose

File--->Export

choose "android Export android Application"

select Your Project you want Export it

where you want it

then start creating new keystore or you have one choose it

Or you can right click on your app you want export then choose export signed android package

[image]

Comment: i did those steps before but it keep give me this error ,, whyy?

Comment: @minafawzy you need to select the path of the keystore, type the password, and on next screen select the key and re-enter the password, then make sure the apk is exported, you can set different name for singed apk to distinguish it from the debug version, EXPORT MIGHT fail for any reason, and you think the APK at bin folder is signed, which is not ... a different name is good idea

Comment: I thought he new then he will create his first keystore , its easy to create just select where he want save it , give it a name , and you right you should change the name if any error occurred (& prefer place where you save your apk also)

Comment: sorry Mina, i wanted to tag @sereen :)

Comment: its OK I hope he fix his problem