# can't display map in my android application

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I try to develop an application that uses map service,my phone is Galaxy S4 version 4.2.2,my problem is that I done every thing correctly,even the permissions of internet connections line that:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.xxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.xxxxx.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.xxxxxx.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.OpenGLESV2" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
        <uses-permission 

android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

I can display the map with my phone normally,but in my application I can't display it :(
any idea pleaze,thanks for Help

update:(logcat )

```
01-16 18:54:45.077: D/jdwp(25516): sendBufferedRequest : len=0x41
01-16 18:54:45.226: D/ActivityThread(25516): BIND_APPLICATION handled : 0 / AppBindData{appInfo=ApplicationInfo{41796770 com.ISITCOM.allotaxii}}
01-16 18:54:45.588: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 59K, 9% free 9329K/10179K, paused 23ms
01-16 18:54:45.591: I/dalvikvm-heap(25516): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.491MB for 1344016-byte allocation
01-16 18:54:45.793: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 10640K/11527K, paused 83ms
01-16 18:54:45.876: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 10641K/11527K, paused 53ms
01-16 18:54:45.958: I/dalvikvm-heap(25516): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.376MB for 3025936-byte allocation
01-16 18:54:46.115: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 13596K/14535K, paused 2ms+2ms
01-16 18:54:46.703: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1319K, 16% free 12313K/14535K, paused 44ms
01-16 18:54:46.771: I/dalvikvm-heap(25516): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.462MB for 7695376-byte allocation
01-16 18:54:46.822: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 19827K/22087K, paused 5ms+5ms
01-16 18:54:47.583: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 19828K/22087K, paused 14ms
01-16 18:54:47.788: I/dalvikvm-heap(25516): Grow heap (frag case) to 35.974MB for 17314576-byte allocation
01-16 18:54:47.938: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 6% free 36736K/39047K, paused 69ms+18ms
01-16 18:54:48.412: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x4cd32000
01-16 18:54:48.412: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=11 (Thread-3189): calling run()
01-16 18:54:48.442: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{41797bf0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41797418 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.SplashScreen}}
01-16 18:54:48.529: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{41797bf0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41797418 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.SplashScreen}}
01-16 18:54:48.671: D/libEGL(25516): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
01-16 18:54:48.686: D/libEGL(25516): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_mtk.so
01-16 18:54:48.712: D/libEGL(25516): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mtk.so
01-16 18:54:48.716: D/libEGL(25516): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mtk.so
01-16 18:54:48.819: D/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Enabling debug mode 0
01-16 18:54:49.104: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.149: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.182: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.215: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.249: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.283: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.318: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.352: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.387: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.420: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.455: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.488: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.521: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.554: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.588: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.622: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.656: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.689: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.722: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.756: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.790: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.824: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.858: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.891: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.924: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.958: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:49.991: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.025: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.060: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.094: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.128: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.162: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.196: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.229: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.263: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.297: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.330: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.364: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.397: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.433: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.468: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.501: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.537: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.571: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.604: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.638: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.674: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.707: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.741: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.775: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.809: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.842: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.874: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.908: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.942: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:50.976: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.010: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.043: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.077: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.109: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.143: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.177: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.211: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.245: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.279: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.313: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.347: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.381: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.414: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.447: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.481: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.515: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.549: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.583: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.617: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.651: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.685: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.718: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.752: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.787: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.820: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.854: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.888: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.922: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.956: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:51.991: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.025: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.058: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.092: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.132: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.165: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.198: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.231: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.265: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.298: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.331: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.364: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.398: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.432: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.471: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.493: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=11: exiting
01-16 18:54:52.493: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=11: bye!
01-16 18:54:52.493: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=0: freeing
01-16 18:54:52.496: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41797bf0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41797418 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.SplashScreen}}
01-16 18:54:52.504: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@41797418
01-16 18:54:52.540: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::parseJpg addr:0x4d21f000, size:7166, fd:56
01-16 18:54:52.547: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::parseJpg reply:0
01-16 18:54:52.548: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::getJpgInfo 168 103 (0)
01-16 18:54:52.548: D/skia(25516): The file input width: 168, height: 103, output width: 168, height: 103, format: 6, prefer size: 0, dither: 0
01-16 18:54:52.549: D/MdpService(25516): get proc handler 0xc3ee9560
01-16 18:54:52.555: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::decodeJpg reply:0
01-16 18:54:52.649: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{417e9b38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417e9358 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.Authentification}}
01-16 18:54:52.653: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{417e9b38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417e9358 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.Authentification}}
01-16 18:54:52.802: W/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture
01-16 18:54:52.985: D/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-16 18:54:53.007: E/GraphicBufferAllocator(25516): FATAL: can't find the mmumapper module
01-16 18:54:53.180: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-DESTROY_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@41797418
01-16 18:54:56.574: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int datax = 12
01-16 18:54:56.574: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_x = 1.200000
01-16 18:54:56.574: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int datay = 16
01-16 18:54:56.574: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_y = 1.600000
01-16 18:54:56.693: D/Input(25516): m =7
01-16 18:54:56.694: D/Input(25516): xvelocity before =0.011131
01-16 18:54:56.694: D/Input(25516): yvelocity before =-327.573944
01-16 18:54:56.694: D/Input(25516): 1 y[m-1]=320.495911
01-16 18:54:56.694: D/Input(25516): 1 y[0]=259.567261
01-16 18:54:56.694: D/Input(25516): 1 y[m-1]-y[0]=60.928650
01-16 18:54:56.694: D/Input(25516): xvelocity=0.011131
01-16 18:54:56.695: D/Input(25516): yvelocity=-327.573944
01-16 18:54:56.695: D/Input(25516):  fwq outVx=0.013358
01-16 18:54:56.695: D/Input(25516):  fwq outVy=-524.118347
01-16 18:54:58.596: D/Input(25516): m =7
01-16 18:54:58.596: D/Input(25516): xvelocity before =171.395432
01-16 18:54:58.597: D/Input(25516): yvelocity before =-409.196808
01-16 18:54:58.597: D/Input(25516): 2 x[m-1]=462.037415
01-16 18:54:58.597: D/Input(25516): 2 x[0]=478.004150
01-16 18:54:58.597: D/Input(25516): 2 x[m-1]-x[0]=-15.966736
01-16 18:54:58.597: D/Input(25516): 1 y[m-1]=273.550903
01-16 18:54:58.597: D/Input(25516): 1 y[0]=206.629242
01-16 18:54:58.597: D/Input(25516): 1 y[m-1]-y[0]=66.921661
01-16 18:54:58.598: D/Input(25516): xvelocity=171.395432
01-16 18:54:58.598: D/Input(25516): yvelocity=-409.196808
01-16 18:54:58.598: D/Input(25516):  fwq outVx=205.674530
01-16 18:54:58.598: D/Input(25516):  fwq outVy=-654.714905
01-16 18:54:59.918: V/Provider/Setting(25516): invalidate [system]: current 18 != cached 0
01-16 18:54:59.929: I/System.out(25516): selectedId2131099684
01-16 18:54:59.930: I/System.out(25516): radioSexButtonandroid.widget.RadioButton@4183e030
01-16 18:54:59.997: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=11: interp stack at 0x4df15000
01-16 18:54:59.997: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=11 (Retrofit-Idle): calling run()
01-16 18:55:00.173: I/System.out(25516): [socket][0] connection /192.168.1.66:8082;LocalPort=59841(15000)
01-16 18:55:00.174: I/System.out(25516): [CDS]connect[/192.168.1.66:8082] tm:15
01-16 18:55:00.175: D/Posix(25516): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.ISITCOM.allotaxii :8082 
01-16 18:55:00.724: I/System.out(25516): [socket][/192.168.1.86:59841]
01-16 18:55:00.724: I/System.out(25516): rx timeout:20000
01-16 18:55:01.066: I/System.out(25516): successyes
01-16 18:55:01.099: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{417e9b38 token=android.os.BinderProxy@417e9358 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.Authentification}}
01-16 18:55:01.111: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@417e9358
01-16 18:55:01.178: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=12: interp stack at 0x4df1d000
01-16 18:55:01.179: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{418d8e40 token=android.os.BinderProxy@418d8658 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.Menu.MainActivity}}
01-16 18:55:01.182: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{418d8e40 token=android.os.BinderProxy@418d8658 {com.ISITCOM.allotaxii/com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.Menu.MainActivity}}
01-16 18:55:01.187: D/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=12 (Retrofit-Idle): calling run()
01-16 18:55:01.229: I/System.out(25516): rx timeout:1
01-16 18:55:01.245: I/System.out(25516): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
01-16 18:55:01.245: I/System.out(25516): [CDS]read is 0
01-16 18:55:01.256: I/System.out(25516): rx timeout:20000
01-16 18:55:01.260: I/System.out(25516): rx timeout:20000
01-16 18:55:01.429: D/OpenGLRenderer(25516): Flushing caches (mode 0)
01-16 18:55:01.606: D/ActivityThread(25516): ACT-STOP_ACTIVITY_HIDE handled : 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@417e9358
01-16 18:55:01.973: I/System.out(25516): success
01-16 18:55:01.973: I/System.out(25516): list1
01-16 18:55:01.988: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::parseJpg addr:0x4d1b8000, size:8567, fd:54
01-16 18:55:01.989: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::parseJpg reply:0
01-16 18:55:01.990: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::getJpgInfo 204 204 (0)
01-16 18:55:01.990: D/skia(25516): The file input width: 204, height: 204, output width: 204, height: 204, format: 6, prefer size: 0, dither: 1
01-16 18:55:01.991: D/MdpService(25516): get proc handler 0xc3ee9560
01-16 18:55:01.997: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::decodeJpg reply:0
01-16 18:55:01.997: D/Getview(25516): Passed5
01-16 18:55:02.002: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::parseJpg addr:0x4d1b8000, size:8567, fd:54
01-16 18:55:02.004: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::parseJpg reply:0
01-16 18:55:02.004: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::getJpgInfo 204 204 (0)
01-16 18:55:02.005: D/skia(25516): The file input width: 204, height: 204, output width: 204, height: 204, format: 6, prefer size: 0, dither: 1
01-16 18:55:02.006: D/MdpService(25516): get proc handler 0xc3ee9560
01-16 18:55:02.011: D/MdpService(25516): BpMdpService::decodeJpg reply:0
01-16 18:55:02.012: D/Getview(25516): Passed5
01-16 18:55:04.994: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int datax = 12
01-16 18:55:04.994: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_x = 1.200000
01-16 18:55:04.994: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int datay = 16
01-16 18:55:04.995: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_y = 1.600000
01-16 18:55:04.995: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int datax = 12
01-16 18:55:04.995: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_x = 1.200000
01-16 18:55:04.996: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int datay = 16
01-16 18:55:04.996: D/Input(25516): VelocityTracker: int m_velocity_magnify_y = 1.600000
01-16 18:55:05.290: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25516): Google Play services is missing.
01-16 18:55:05.315: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25516): Google Play services is missing.
01-16 18:55:05.317: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25516): Google Play services is missing.
01-16 18:55:05.320: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25516): Google Play services is missing.
01-16 18:55:05.323: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25516): Google Play services is missing.
01-16 18:55:05.330: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25516): Google Play services is missing.
01-16 18:55:05.338: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(25516): Google Play services is missing.
01-16 18:55:05.339: D/AndroidRuntime(25516): Shutting down VM
01-16 18:55:05.339: W/dalvikvm(25516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e79258)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at com.ISITCOM.allotaxii.Menu.Map.onCreateView(Map.java:63)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:834)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1038)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1396)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
01-16 18:55:05.343: E/AndroidRuntime(25516):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 18:55:05.369: D/dalvikvm(25516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 26020K, 67% free 13272K/39367K, paused 2ms+5ms
```

Comment: Here is a good tutorial please follow this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-working-with-google-maps/

Comment: have you added MAP key ?

Comment: I think the problem is in my phone :(

Comment: can you add the complete manifest and map class here

Comment: i guess prob is in ur key.
Have u declare ur key in manifest?

Comment: I puted them @Dorami

Comment: I have followed all the steps in this tutorielhttps://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key ,but always the same problem I can't display the map in my application with the message "the application xxx has stopped suddenly"

Comment: Are you running a signed apk in device? i am sure, the problem should be there

Comment: can you explain more pleaze :) @Bhavik Mehta

Comment: when you use Maps, Facebook, Twitter etc in your Application you have to Export a Signed APK from Eclipse/Android Studio and then install that apk into your device to check if Map is displaying or not
Follow [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)! to Export Signed APK

Comment: theres a space in your key:
    android:value=" AIzaSyD044sYPIO4jz2CnK9v2xmLGg1xLAeWYIs"
should be
    android:value="AIzaSyD044sYPIO4jz2CnK9v2xmLGg1xLAeWYIs"

Comment: @N Dorigatti  I deleted the space and I get the problem all the time it's said "the application xxx has stopped suddenly" when I clic th map button in my application

Comment: @Lina can you post your logcat please?

Comment: @Lina you are not handling the map fragment properly, Thats why it is causing NullPointer

Comment: what should I do to handle it corectly :(

Comment: @Lina Are you adding Google Play Service Library as supported dependency?

Comment: @Bhavik Mehta yes I added it

Comment: @Lina Then it should not say Google Play services is missing! anyways, you should post your whole code here, or email me your code to have a look @bhavikmehta5491@gmail.com