# Control and view of core TV functions

Tags: android, android-tv

I am interested in Android TV.

I need to control core TV functions from an App:

1. Live TV in the background of my App
2. List the channels the TV knows of
3. Selecting a channel on the TV

Is that possible with an Android TV through the SDK?

Comment: AFAIK, no, because Android TV is not necessarily a TV. Set-top boxes powered by Android TV (e.g., Nexus Player) have only an HDMI connection to the TV. A regular TV does not "know" channels, let alone have a means of delivering that data over HDMI. I don't recall if these standalone Android TV devices are required to ship with "IR blasters" to control the TV tuner, or whether there is SDK options for using one.

Comment: We acquired a Philips 6500 Android TV. So it is a fully fledged TV, not a STB. However, if the code is supposed to work on both - and has no access to the underlying functions, then this could be quite a roadblock for us.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with the SDK right now, especially not for a third party app.

Comment: @CommonsWare: If you would write your comment as an answer, I think it is enough to answer my question. I am relatively certain that there is no way to do what I want to do. At least, right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible, if you are building third-party app.

> 1. Live TV in the background of my App

It is not recommended by [TV App Quality](http://developer.android.com/distribute/essentials/quality/tv.html), it says

> TV-TR:
>   App does not partially obscure other apps. App fills the entire screen and has a non-transparent background.

> 2. List the channels the TV knows of 
> 3. Selecting a channel on the TV

Android TV provides a [TV Provider](https://source.android.com/devices/tv/#tv_provider) platform which stores the channels and programs from TV inputs. However you need  `ACCESS_ALL_EPG_DATA` permission to access other app's TV Provider database which is only available with `signatureOrSystem` app.
There is another related post here, [Android Tv: get list of channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679142/android-tv-get-list-of-channels).