# How can i find Channel list in android tv

Tags: android, channel, television

Is there any way to retrive all the channels list through code in Android running on it? I would like to get all the channel names and descriptions of every channel and use it on my Android TV application.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679142/android-tv-get-list-of-channels

Comment: access only own channel list