# Browser key which i have generated is not working

Tags: android

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/    I have followed the above link for autocomplete google place api it is working same downloaded but when i replace its browser key to mine its not working json returning url:    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyCkTiGVHkYRYisbXSwVzFOaI2CZQ50JdJQ&components=country:gr&input=mum

i have enabled Google Places API for Android still it what api should i enabled                        Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you sign the APK??

Comment: how should i sign it?? i mean how to sign apk ??

Comment: if you are using eclipse see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file) , or if you using studio see this [link](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: make sure you are using browser key not android key from Google API console.

Comment: I have signed the apk still it is not working @Manikanta

Comment: I have used browser key not android key @techroid

Comment: can anyone fix it ...

Comment: I have solved it by using these steps : 1) enable google places api for android      2) enable google places api web services     3)use server key instead of browser key