# Keytool Error while creating android apk file

Tags: android, apk, keytool

I have just created a Android application with android studio while building a .apk with Key Store, it shows an error.

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: My Application (Access
>   is denied)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old post but I bumped into the same problem today.  Therefore, I am answering this question so that going forward java developers can find their mistake right away!

**The very sad part is [Android developer site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file) is not clear on what characters are allowed while generating the certificate for the Signed APK.  That is just stupid from the documentation perspective to me.**  May be because no one has tried it or tested it with special characters!

In my case it was failing because of the following:

1. my last name has apostrophe in it and it is a invalid character
2. in Organization I used, period and comma which are invalid
   characters as well

**Therefore, the simple answer is just use plain text characters in order to proceed.  Space is accepted!**

However, you have to try other characters one by one and see which ones are allowed and which one are not.  The sad part is, the error message is a vague message like we used get error message back in 80s like "Errors Occured!".  Come on Java you can do better than that.  Based on the message I am getting, it seems like it is the Java API issue and not Android but I may be wrong....