# You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, apk

So I'm trying to upload my APK to the Google Play Store, but then I'm getting this **"You uploaded an APK that was signed in debug mode. You need to sign your APK in release mode."** even tho I have set my app to release mode in every place that I could find in visual studio. I don't know what I'm doing wrong... Any help? [image: Here's what my vs project settings look like.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sign an android apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure it is signed correctly with the method that Xamarin has provided you.

Please refer back to the docs and guides of Xamarin.

[Here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/) is the link to signing the APK using Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks for your help! That article made me realize that I was selecting the wrong setting. What I was doing was exporting the APK from the setting ***Build>Export Android Package***, instead of ***Tools>Android>Publish Android App***.

Comment: No worries! You should go through the Developer documents/guids in Xamarin Developer website if you haven't already. They're really useful. :)