# ionic3 cordova build android --prod --release don't get the desired effect

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

CIL Version Info

```
node v8.4.0
cordova v7.0.1
ionic v3.9.2
```

I create a tabs project; then use cmd:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

a unsigned release version apk ,signe info:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhu4A.png)

After signature,run apk in device (my device android version:4.4.4), Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0g0mE.png)

Anybody know what's going on?

Comment: try this "command ionic cordova build android --dev--release"

Comment: You should assign the release after in the command line. You will find more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, get rid of -- prod, without this problem, but the app starts slowly, it takes 9 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved，use **cnpm install** has this Problem , use **npm install** no problem;