# Can't get apk file from Ecilpes

Tags: android

**I have export signed project but  I can't get the apk file . i got file which has file type 'file' how can I get signed apk file from it . Plz help**

Comment: What!!????? check the directory you specified for the apk not the key you created..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417122/how-to-use-eclipse-to-create-released-signed-apk follow steps mentiond in this question