# Android Proguard: How to set up in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

I am trying to set up `ProGuard` for a standard "Hello World" application in `Eclipse`.

I have taken the step of uncommenting the line in `project.properties`, However Proguard is not enabled.

What is wrong with my code / what am I missing?

Code is shown below, note that I have named the  application Proguard.

**Project.properties:**

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
#To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-20
android.library.reference.1=../appcompat_v7
```

**proguard-project.txt:**

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Comment: Proguard will run when you build your App release version in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for your help, how do I run an app in release version? Any links for tutorials would be great!

Comment: take a look here `http://stackoverflow.com/a/3417157/1602333`

Comment: Is it possible to use "Export unsigned Application Package" as I am not actually wanting to release this app, it is just to test proguard

Comment: I.e. I dont want to add it to the playstore, I just want to obtain the .apk file in order to test if proguard has been correctly implemented on it

Comment: so test the same with the release version.

Comment: Yes but I am wondering if "Export unsigned Application Package" will give me a release version on which proguard has been implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Proguard will only work on release builds -(Signed && unSigned). So go to your manifest and play around the exporting feature

also addressing your comment questions, yes it will be implemented, but without a signature.., Once proguard is implemented it will show a proguard folder,that's how you know proguard is active..

For more information on how proguard worked && etc, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714914/android-how-to-check-proguard-obfuscation-has-worked/27715191#27715191)