# Proguard: List of removed

Tags: android, proguard

I want to check which classes and methods were removed.
Any way to achieve this?

I know mapping.txt shows which symbols is obfuscated to what.
But what is removed is not listed there as I know.
[Proguard web site](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) does not describe about this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The option [`-printusage`](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#printusage) writes out the unused classes, fields, and methods.

Android Gradle builds by default write it to `build/outputs/mapping/release/usage.txt`.

Comment: thanks! I didnt notice it caz searching about "remove" verb :(  I also find d.android.com which mentions about usage.txt. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html

Answer (score 7):

Add the following rules in `proguard-rules.pro` file in your Gradel Scripts directory

- **Generate a report of removed (or kept) code**

  add `-printusage usage.txt`
- **To check report of the entry points that R8 determines from your project’s keep rules**

  add `-printseeds seeds.txt`

after this, build signed apk. Then at the root of your projects these files will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

`usage.txt` is your choice to find what were removed - list of what Proguard does not keep

[[Read more here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59285427/4770877)