# What does j.u.v. stand for in `java.lang.ClassCastException: j.u.v cannot be cast to kotlin.collections.MutableList`

Tags: java, android, kotlin, classcastexception

I am seeing a bunch of ClassCastException crashes in my project and the stacktrace describing:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: j.u.v cannot be cast to kotlin.collections.MutableList
```

I can't seem to figure out or find what the `j.u.v.` stands for.

Anyone?

Comment: you cannot tell easily. If that's your project, disable proguard and try again. If that's not your code, then without the map you will not be easily able to tell what was the original name before proguard mangled it.

Comment: If that is the literal text of the error message, it means a Java class called `v` in a package called `j.u`. More likely you have abbreviated it, or someone has, and it refers to say `java.util.Vector`.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked for a moment that j.u.v. of course seems to point to an obfuscated classname..

As to @RyanM question. That post you linked to there isn't that helpful for most people. This one is way better: [Android - How to check Proguard obfuscation has worked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714914/android-how-to-check-proguard-obfuscation-has-worked)

For who wants to figure out to what class the obfuscated classname refers to you can either check the mappings.txt file in the build -> outputs -> mapping folder.

Or another way to figure out to which the obfuscated file/method name relates to is use the apk analyzer (build -> Analyze APK)