# Android sign akp for Google Play java 6 switch on Windows

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk, sign

I have warning when signing akp:

```
jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
This jar contains signatures that does not include a timestamp. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2141-02-03) or after any future revocation date.
```

Here: [“Package file was not signed correctly” error — detect whether or not it will happen with Google Play app apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034663/package-file-was-not-signed-correctly-error-detect-whether-or-not-it-will-h) I've read it may lead to issues on Google Play and as I understand advice is to sign with java 6, code how to switch temporarily is given for OSX. I use Windows 7, I've installed java 6 but when I run jarsigner from 6 it gives error:

```
Registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\CurrentVersion'
has value '1.7', but '1.6' is required.
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

How to switch temporariry to java 6 for Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

I desistalled Java 7/6, installed 6 and used jarsinger from java 6 to sign, then even used keytool from java 6 for new keystore:

java 6 jarsigner does not give warnings on akp generated by it, however, when I tried to verify apk with jarsigner from java 8, same warnings were generated, so the point is not java 6 makes singed apk better than new 7/8, but new 7/8 give more details about result.

Hope my generated by Android Studio 1.5 keys will be fine for Google Play.