# I can not create an apk on my eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

So I am trying to create an apk via eclipse for a small app I created (one of my first) but after going through several tutorials I can't find the android option which is suppose to present in Export. My Eclipse version is Mars.2 Release (4.5.2). I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. 
[image: those are my export options.]

Comment: Debug apk is built every time a change is made if `Build Automatically` is enabled.  For release apk see here:  [Android Application APK signing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916053/android-application-apk-signing)

Comment: In my eclipse I have a Android selection after general. Have you added the Andriod packages to eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install the sdk first. It's not included in eclipse.

[How to setup eclipse for android app development](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Setup-Eclipse-for-Android-App-Development/)

A personal recommendation:
Use Android Studio, you will have to get used to it but after 3 months I prefer it over eclipse. Also you should consider it since google stopped supporting Eclipse. [android studio is the official android IDE](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

Comment: @shahz so did my answer help you? If you tell me what you miss maybe I can point you to a helpful tutorial.

Comment: Yes it did help me but I have just posted another question as I ended up facing another issue related to exporting my project into an apk. The link to my new question is;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761086/creating-an-apk-via-eclipse