# creating an apk via eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735499/i-can-not-create-an-apk-on-my-eclipse) earlier and I followed the instructions I was given in the [answer](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Setup-Eclipse-for-Android-App-Development/). Now I get the android option, which I was not getting earlier, as per the image below
[image: export options]

I select the option: Export Android Application after which I get a message that the project I am trying to export is not an Android project. This is really confusing and I took an android development course and the project I am trying to convert to an apk is one of the first i created. The following screenshot is the message I see;
[image: Select Project to Export]

When I click on the browse button all i get is a new window but nothing gets populated in it. I need help/guidance people as I am learning android development and I am still a rookie :(

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like either:

1. Your project isn't opened yet

> Right click on project name in Package Explorer > Open Project

2. Your project may have been accidentally marked as a Library project (library projects cannot be exported as apk files)

> Right click on project name in Package Explorer > Properties > Android > "Is Library" checkbox

3. Your project may not have been imported into Eclipse yet. To do so,
   open package explorer and add your project into it:

To view package explorer:

> Window > Show View > Package Exporer

To import new project:

> New > Project... > Android Project from Existing Code > [Look for root
>   directory of the Android project, should be the root dir containing
>   the `AndroidManifest.xml` file] > Select project to import (if you
>   have the previous step correctly you should only see one) > Select
>   Copy projects into workspace (if you want to create a copy in your
>   workspace folder, otherwise ensure that your project files don't move
>   out of your existing directory) > Finish

4. Your project may have been accidentally been configured as a Java project instead of an Android application project, if so see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959820/convert-existing-project-into-android-project-in-eclipse).

If that's not the reason why you are not seeing any projects, please let me know and provide more information (perhaps also a screenshot of your entire IDE with the Java perspective).

---

This is what the project properties panel should look like:

[image: Resource, Android, Android Lint Preferences, Builders, Java Build Path, Java Code Style, Java Compiler, Java Editor, Javadoc Location, Project References, Refactoring History, Run/Debug Settings, Task Repository, Task Tags, Validation, WikiText]

Comment: My project is open (check screenshot 1) and as for step 2 I cant find the Android in properties (screenshot2). As for step 3 I made a very simple java code as a starter in eclipse. The screenshot has the file structure. Please highlight what rookie mistake I have made. Thanks in advance :) (I have added the screenshots in my question)

Comment: Found the problem. You may have accidentally created a Java project instead of an Android project. Try creating a brand new Android project to see if the options appear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think yours is an Android project but it a Java project.
It uses JRE to compile so it is a Java project.
You are trying to export Android application from Java project.